# Integration of kubernetes API

Tags: api, kubernetes, frameworks

I am working on developing a distributed communication platform, and I'm looking for using Kubernetes API to manage containers' life cycle..

Do you have any idea on how to use or integrate kubernetes API inside a program ? Or we must opt for scripts

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit odd to use Kubernetes API to manage containers lifecycle, it will be interesting to understand exactly what is your case.
Generally speaking, you have Kubernetes clients available in multiple languages to achieve that: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/